# how to store user input and populate listview from data in mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, xml, listview, android-fragments

i have a tabbed layout with fragments on each page. on the first page there is a user input box and button that when inputted and clicked gives a toast. i would like to store the string of data in my mysql database and populate the list view on another fragment with data stored in the table from mysql. Was wondering how to go about this exactly?

main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the viewpager in activity_main.xml
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    // Set the ViewPagerAdapter into ViewPager
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

}

public void btnShout(View v) {
    //allows for label to be changed to shouted once button is pressed
    EditText txtInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtInput);
    TextView lblShout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblShout);
    lblShout.setText("Shouted! ");

    //allows for toast to be displayed once button is clicked
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
    toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, txtInput.getText() + " Has Been Shouted.", toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

here is my activity main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

viewpageradapter class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
// Tab Titles
private String tabtitles[] = new String[] {"Home","Shouts","Shouts" };
Context context;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}


public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {

        // Open Fragment home.java
        case 0:
            FragmentHome fragmenthome = new FragmentHome();
            return fragmenthome;

        // Open Fragment shouters.java
        case 1:
            FragmentShouts fragmentshouts = new FragmentShouts();
            return fragmentshouts;

        case 2:
            FragmentShouts fragmentShouts = new FragmentShouts();
            return fragmentShouts;



    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return tabtitles[position];
}
```

here is my tab with the user input (home fragment class)

```
public class FragmentHome extends Fragment {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragment home.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenthome, container, false);
    return view;

}
```

here is fragment home xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="New Shout"
    android:id="@+id/lblShout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="134dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtInput"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblShout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:hint="Enter New Shout..." />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="SHOUT"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtInput"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="btnShout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the fragment with the listview (shouts fragment class)

```
public class FragmentShouts extends Fragment {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragment shouts.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentshouts, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

here is the fragment shouts xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:contextClickable="true">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you mean MySQL database? Or do you mean SQLite database?

Comment: MySQL since I like the terminal feel of it

Comment: You can't run a MySQL instance on an Android device. So, are you thinking of a web server approach where the Web service is hosted on a server which has access to the MySQL database?
So basically the Android application does not access the MySQL database.

Comment: Yeah I guess so now lol, I didn't know that but I knew a lot of people used a web service or a web hosting site

Comment: Okay @Alexander. Hope it solved your problem.